# How to modify a read only files under windows folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I am facing a problem in Windows 7. Usually I can do this in Windows XP, but after moving to windows 7, I can't do it anymore. Below are the details.
I need to modify some files in a specific folder A under windows folder. These files are readonly files. And I don't have any priviledge to change it. But I can modify it by making the folder A as a share folder. And access it the shared folder A via Run....
This can be done in XP. But, in windows 7, I couldn't do it.
Any idea to resolve this issue? In my opinion, I might modify it by installing another OS, but I am hoping there will be a simpler way to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you were able to do this in Windows XP it was only because of a security flaw within Windows XP. You are not suppose to be able to modify a read-only file in Windows.

Comment: If you don't have admin access you are not allowed to modify files in the Windows folder and other critical system locations any more.

Comment: the read only files are because of I installed third party software. I need to modify it, but Win 7 permissions are different with Win XP. :(

Answer (score 1):

Sharing settings in Windows 7 are a bit different. Make sure that you set permissions correctly under the Security tab in addition to the share permissions themselves. Granting permissions under the sharing options isn't enough.

If this ends up not being the issue, booting into another OS isn't a bad idea.  You wouldn't need to "install" another OS, you could just boot into a Linux distro using a Live CD.

Comment: I tried your idea and use Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD. And it's not working. I can modify the file, but I cannot chmod the file. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What are you hoping to do by chmod'ing it?  It's likely an NTFS partition, so it won't modify the Windows permissions.  Your original question was about modifying them, but if you need to do more with the files than modify them, I'd copy them off onto a flash drive or something under Ubuntu, then boot back into Windows and copy them back to the hard drive.

Comment: um, i understand now, it is because of NTFS -.- but I already figured the solution. Thanks anyway